# Initialising Python dictionary with list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

I coded up this code randomly trying to learn comprehension and now I am unable to understand what is happening in the code.

```
lst = "this is really strange behaviour".split()
dt = dict({i,j} for i,j in enumerate(lst))
print(dt)
```

I tried to make a dictionary with keys as integers and values as corresponding words. But the output of this code is

```
{0: 'this', 1: 'is', 2: 'really', 'strange': 3, 4: 'behaviour'}
```

I don't understand why some keys are numbers while others are strings.
P.S. I don't even understand why this syntax is correct and gives no errors.
Please explain about it. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{i,j}` creates a set. Sets have no inherit order, so the set is sometimes `i, j` and sometimes `j, i`. `dict` always use the "first" (left-most) value as the key and the "second" as the value. This means that sometimes `i` is picked to be the key and sometimes `j` is.

Use an ordered data-structure instead, for example a tuple:

```
dt = dict((i, j) for i, j in enumerate(lst))
#         ^    ^  note parenthesis to create tuple, not braces
```

then `dt` will always be

```
{0: 'this', 1: 'is', 2: 'really', 3: 'strange', 4: 'behaviour'}
```

You can actually skip `(i, j) for i, j in enumerate(lst)` which does nothing useful really, and go straight with

```
dt = dict(enumerate(lst))
```

Using a set here does not make any sense. Since elements of a set are unique, this code will break if the list contains a number which happens to equal its index, for example:

```
lst = ['a', 1]
dt = dict({i, j} for i, j in enumerate(lst))
```

Will cause an error

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element 1 has length 1; 2 is required
```

because `{1, 1}` becomes `{1}` and `dict` expects a sequence of key-value pairs.

Comment: Is it usual that ```print({2,'really'}, {0,'this'}, {3,'strange'})``` always prints what is expected  (i.e. int followed by string ) ? Why isn't order here changed any time ?

Comment: @Harshraj do it enough times and you will see that sometimes the order does change. I just got `{'really', 2} {0, 'this'} {3: 'strange'}` printed

Comment: Ohhh, yes, after having lots of set, I see this effect. Thanks @DeepSpace